# PHP Access variable in require class

Tags: php, class, variables, global, require

I'm currently working on a Web project and I need assistance to setup a clone.

I have installed WampServer 2.2 (because it use some deprecated function)

Some pages use this:

**config.php**

```
$projectpage = 'folder/projection.php';
```

**Mainpage.php**

```
require 'config.php';
require $projectpage;
```

On these pages the browser display :

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: Filename cannot be empty...
```

It's probably a bad setting in Wamp but I didn't found it :(

(I have tried to turn on `register_globals` in `php.ini` and it didn't made any difference)

Thanks

Comment: It just tells you that `$projectpage` is not defined in the scope where `require` is called or overwriten. Show the content of `config.php`

Answer (score 0):

`$projectpage` is defined directly in a class

This code works on the production server, so I think it's a setting in Wamp

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's a common gotcha which is why I knew that was likely the cause.